# How can i write an array starting from right to left in C++

Tags: c++, arrays, for-loop, nested-loops

I don't want to reverse or shift the array. What I want is to write the array from right to left.

I did something like

```
int arr[5] = {0};
for (int i = 0; i < 5; i++)
{
    cout << "enter a number : ";
    cin >> arr[i];
    for (int j = 0; j < 5; j++)
    {
        if (arr[j] != 0)
        {
            cout << arr[j] << " ";
        }
        else
            cout << "X ";
    }
    
    cout << endl;
    
}
```

and on the output screen I see this

```
enter a number : 5
5 X X X X
enter a number : 4
5 4 X X X
enter a number : 3
5 4 3 X X
enter a number : 2
5 4 3 2 X
enter a number : 1
5 4 3 2 1
Press any key to continue . . .
```

**but i want to see this**

```
enter a number : 5
X X X X 5
enter a number : 4
X X X 5 4
enter a number : 3
X X 5 4 3
enter a number : 2
X 5 4 3 2
enter a number : 1
5 4 3 2 1
Press any key to continue . . .
```

**how can I do that?**

**I will be glad if you help.**

Comment: Hint: `for (int i = 0; i < 5; i++)` is something to look at.

Comment: Also, if the user enters "0" for the array value, you will get incorrect output.

Comment: Why is using `arr[4-j]` instead of `arr[j]` not the answer? What am I missing?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just change the inner for loop for example the following way

```
int j = 5;

for ( ; j != 0 && arr[j-1] == 0; --j )
{
    std::cout << 'X' << ' ';
}

for ( int k = 0; k != j; k++ )
{
    std::cout << arr[k] << ' ';
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you are trying to write into the last index each time, and then move each number backwards in the array?

To write into the last index use cin >> arr[4].
Then After printing out the array copy each value into the previous index. Make sure that your copy only when the J index is less than 4

```
int arr[5] = {0};
for (int i = 0; i < 5; i++)
{
    cout << "enter a number : ";
    //write into the last position
    cin >> arr[4];

    for (int j = 0; j < 5; j++)
    {
        if (arr[j] != 0)
        {
            cout << arr[j] << " ";
        }
        else
            cout << "X ";
        
        //don't go out of bounds. This should move each number to the previous index
        if(j<4){
            arr[j]=arr[j+1];
        }
    }
    
    cout << endl;
    
}
```